# using subprocess over different files python

Tags: python, file, subprocess

I've got a problem with a short script, it'd be great if you could have a look!

```
import os
import subprocess

root = "/Users/software/fmtomov1.0/remaker_lastplot/source_relocation/observed_arrivals_loc3d"

def loop_loc3d(file_in):
    """Loops loc3d over the source files"""
    return subprocess.call (['loc3d'], shell=True)

def relocation ():
    for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(root):
        for file in files:
            file_in = open(os.path.join(subdir, file), 'r')
            return loop_loc3d(file_in)
```

I think the script is quite easy to understand, it's very simple. However I'm not getting the result wanted. In a few word I just want 'loc3d' to operate over all the files contents present in the 'observed_arrivals_loc3d' directory, which means that I need to open all the files and that's what I've actually done. In fact, if I try to 'print files' after:

```
for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(root)
```

I'll get the name of every file. Furthermore, if I try a 'print file_in' after

```
file_in = open(os.path.join(subdir, file), 'r')
```

I get something like this line for every file:

```
<open file '/Users/software/fmtomov1.0/remaker_lastplot/source_relocation/observed_arrivals_loc3d/EVENT2580', mode 'r' at 0x78fe38>
```

subprocess has been tested alone on only one file and it's working.

Overall I'm getting no errors but just -11 which means absolutely nothing to me. The output from loc3d should be completly different.

So does the code look fine to you? Is there anything I'm missing? Any suggestion?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: also consider using [`make` as suggested in the comment by @Kirill Teplinskiy](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7938128/4279).

Comment: It's kind of hard to understand that for me. Anyway I tried what you said below and nothing happens (no output no error). At this stage I do think it's a 'loc3d' bug, so probably everything is fine as far as python is concerned. Will try to look deeper into loc3d.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found out that loc3d, as unutbu said, relies on several variables and in the specific case one called 'observal_arrivals' that I have to create and delete every time from my directory. In Pythonic terms it means:

```
import os
import shutil
import subprocess

def loop_loc3d(file_in):
    """Loops loc3d over the source files"""
    return subprocess.call(["loc3d"], shell=True)

path = "/Users/software/fmtomo/remaker_lastplot/source_relocation"
path2 = "/Users/Programming/working_directory/2test"
new_file_name = 'observed_arrivals'
def define_object_file ():
    for filename in os.listdir("."):
        file_in = os.rename (filename, new_file_name) # get the observal_arrivals file
        file_in = shutil.copy ("/Users/simone/Programming/working_directory/2test/observed_arrivals", "/Users/software/fmtomo/remaker_lastplot/source_relocation")
        os.chdir(path) # goes where loc3d is
        loop_loc3d (file_in)
        os.remove("/Users/software/fmtomo/remaker_lastplot/source_relocation/observed_arrivals")
        os.remove ("/Users/Programming/working_directory/2test/observed_arrivals")
        os.chdir(path2)
```

Now, this is working very well, so it should answer my question. I guess it's quite easy to understand, it's just copying, changing dir and that kind of stuff.

Comment: 1. Don't post questions as an answer. 2. There are many things wrong with this code. Read [Python Tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tut). It will save you time. 3. `open('fort.14', 'r')` means: open file  `'fort.14'` for reading. It doesn't create it if the file doesn't exists.

Comment: what should I do in this case? I mean I don't think it is a good idea to ask a new question and I don't think I can post that in a comment. Obviously fort.14 already exists.

Comment: Create a *complete* (i.e., you can run it as is), *minimal* (i.e., the problem vanishes if you remove anything from it) example that shows your problem and post it as a new question. You can add a link to your previous question if you think that it is related.

Comment: Add a complete traceback (lines that you see in the output before `OSError: ...`).

Comment: I've sorted it out... you know what? Never programming during the night, you can make very stupid mistakes. Anyway I'm going to edit this last answer and leave it without the added question

Answer (score 1):

I assume you would call `loc3d filename` from the CLI. If so, then:

```
def loop_loc3d(filename):
    """Loops loc3d over the source files"""
    return subprocess.call (['loc3d',filename])

def relocation():
    for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(root):
        for file in files:
            filename = os.path.join(subdir, file)
            return loop_loc3d(filename)
```

In other words, don't open the file yourself, let `loc3d` do it.

Comment: Does `loc3d filename` work as expected from the command line? Does `loc3d` have a `-v` verbose mode? If so, calling `subprocess.call (['loc3d','-v',filename])` might give you more debugging info.

Comment: Yes it does work....with -v it still works but doesn't give any output now and no errors as well.

Comment: Maybe `loc3d` relies on environment variables which are not present when called from `subprocess.call`. Does `subprocess.Popen('loc3d filename', shell=True)` work?

Comment: If you know the environment variables `loc3d` needs, it is better not to use `shell=True` and instead supply the environment variables directly: `subprocess.Popen(['loc3d',filename],env={'NAME':'VALUE',...})`

Comment: Popen gives the same result (i.e., none). I know what loc3d needs but it's a long list of files. And for example I'm trying to iterate it over 411 files. The strange thing is that it works for a file, but not for all of them.

Answer (score 1):

Currently your relocation method will return after the first iteration (for the first file). You shouldn't need to return at all.

```
def loop_loc3d(filename):
    """Loops loc3d over the source files"""
    return subprocess.call (['loc3d',filename])

def relocation ():
    for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(root):
        for file in files:
            filename = os.path.join(subdir, file)
            loop_loc3d(filename)
```

This is only one of the issues. The other is concerning `loc3d` itself. Try providing the full path for loc3d.

Comment: It looks like it's working for a few seconds but then no output and no errors....

Comment: any idea where I can download loc3d to test it?

Comment: unfortunately you can't and I think I can't attach anything here otherwise it would be a good idea!

Answer (score 0):

`-11` exit code might mean that the command killed by signal Segmentation fault.
It is a bug in `loc3d`. A well-behaved program should not produce 'Segmentation fault' on any user input.

Feed `loc3d` only files that it can understand. Print filenames  or use `subprocess.check_call()` to find out which file it doesn't like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import fnmatch
import os
import subprocess

def loc3d_files(root):
    for dirpath, dirs, files in os.walk(root, topdown=True):
        # skip hidden directories
        dirs[:] = [d for d in dirs if not d.startswith('.')]
        # process only known files
        for file in fnmatch.filter(files, "*some?pattern[0-9][0-9].[ch]"):
            yield os.path.join(dirpath, file)

for path in loc3d_files(root):
    print path
    subprocess.check_call(['loc3d', path]) # raise on any error
```

Comment: Thanks very much J.F., you're really close to the problem, I mean, very often I get 'Segmentation fault'. I'll try that as soon as I can and I'll let you know.

Comment: @eikonal: In the comment you said that nothing happens. If you are talking about the above code then you must change the file pattern `"*some?pattern[0-9][0-9].[ch]"` e.g., to feed all .txt-files to `loc3d` you could use `"*.txt"` file pattern. If you'd like to process files from directories that have names that start with a dot then you must remove `dir[:] = ...` line in the above code. You must see at least something in the output if `loc3d_files()` yields at least one filename.