# Python Batch convert of FLAC files

Tags: python, ogg, os.walk, flac

I want to convert all FLAC files to OGG in the working directory:

This is what I ALREADY have.

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(args):
        flacs = [f for f in files if f.endswith('.flac')]
        oggs = [o for o in files if o.endswith('.ogg')]

        for flacfiles in flacs:
            id3 = ('id3v2', '-C', flacfiles)
            cmd = ('oggenc', '-q7', flacfiles)
            try:
                subprocess.check_call(id3, cwd=root)
                subprocess.check_call(cmd, cwd=root)
            except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
                print "subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command %s returned non-zero exit status 1" % cwd
```

Now I want to know how I can - in the directory containing my FLAC files - check if there is one `.flac` with a `.cue` and if that is the case do_something()

Comment: Also consider [GNU Make](http://www.gnu.org/s/make/).  It was especially developed for solving such tasks.  With [this Makefile](http://www.mat.univie.ac.at/~eno/Makefile.f2o) you get detection of already converted files, ability to launch multiple converter processes in a parallel and much more!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for flacfiles in flacs:
    if os.path.exists(os.path.splitext(flacfiles)[0] + '.cue')):
        # do something
```

Comment: getting a: TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, tuple found